# systemd service with timer as user

Tags: systemd

I am trying to write a service with timers. But it is not being executed:

example@host /etc/systemd/system/mbsync.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mailbox synchronisation service for user example

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mbsync -aV
User=example
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

example@host /etc/systemd/system/mbsync.timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mailbox synchronisation timer

[Timer]
OnBootSec=10s
OnCalendar=*:00/2

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I started the service like this:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable mbsync.timer
systemctl start mbsync.timer
```

But I only get:

```
systemctl list-timers

NEXT LEFT LAST                         PASSED       UNIT         ACTIVATES
Mon 2015-11-30 11:50:00 CET  10s ago       Mon 2015-11-30 11:50:07 CET  2s ago  mbsync.timer                 mbsync.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer *is* executed, but it may not do what you expect.
You should check logs with `systemctl status -l mbsync.service` and tune your `.mbsyncrc` accordingly.

I found these resources helpful:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync#Automatic_synchronization
- https://www.bostonenginerd.com/posts/notmuch-of-a-mail-setup-part-1-mbsync-msmtp-and-systemd/

especially the second one, with *user* unit files, which is required when using `PassCmd "gpg ..."`.